# Can you give me some tips about my work PHP

Tags: php

This is my first PHP question:

There are 2 input strings `$n1` and `$n2`. First one is needed to be a long word for example 'queryselector'. Then the second input is a sub string of first input string (query, tor ... ). I have to find the string position of second input in the first input, ie., where it is, in the beginning or at the end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form method='get'>
        <input type="text" name="n">
        <input type="text" name="a">
        <button>push</button>
    </form>
    <?php
    $n1 = $_GET['n'];
    $n2 = $_GET['a'];
    echo $n1, $n2;
    if (strpos($n1,$n2) !== ''){
            if (strlen($n2) !== '') {
               strpos($n1);
            }
     }
   ?>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are asking for

Comment: you can use `isset()` to check if `$_GET[x]` is defined

Comment: FIrstly, you aren't `submitting` your form by clicking your button, add type="submit" to your button to make it  submit your form.

Comment: did you mean that you want to find small string existence in long string?

Comment: @Martin , a buttons default type is submit (unless browser is IE7 or older).

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need.

```
<?php
$n1 = $_GET['n'];
$n2 = $_GET['a'];
echo $n1, $n2;
if(strpos($n1, $n2) !== ''){
    if(strlen($n2) !== ''){
        if(strpos($n1, $n2) + strlen($n2) == strlen($n1)) //eg., tor
            echo 'At the end';
        else if(strpos($n1, $n2) == 0) //eg., query
            echo 'In the beginning';
        else //eg., sel
            echo 'Somewhere in between';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method='get'>
    <input type="text" name="n">
    <input type="text" name="a">
    <button>push</button>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['n'])&&isset($_GET['a'])){
    if(substr($_GET['n'], 0, strlen($_GET['a'])) === $_GET['a']){
        echo "It's in the start";
    }
    else{
        echo "It's in the end";
    }
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Above code with check your first input and will see if your first input starts with the second input otherwise it will assume it ends with it. But you need to modify that button element and go for a submit button, at least that's what i would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out with the `PHP` code as below:

```
<?php
$n1 = 'queryselector';
$n2 = 'tor';
// echo $n1, $n2;
if (strpos($n1,$n2) !== '') {
    if (strlen($n2) > 0) {
       echo 'Find substring at position: ' . strpos($n1, $n2);
       if (substr($n1, 0, strlen($n2)) == $n2) {
           echo ' & is at Starting.';
       } else if (substr($n1, '-'.strlen($n2)) == $n2) {
           echo ' & is at Ending.';
       } else {
           echo ' & is in Between.';
       }
    }
 }
?>
```

I have place directly the string, you make it dynamic as you did (like `$_GET`).

Here is a [Demo Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/hoET8). You can check here also.

Output will be like: `Find substring at position: 0 & is at Starting.`